# Version of Hall's marriage theorem in arbitrary finite graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite, simple, undirected graph such that $\bigcup E = V$ (that is, every vertex belongs to at least one edge).

For $v\in V$ we set $N(v) = \{w\in V:\{v,w\}\in E\}$, and for $S\subseteq V$ we let $N(S) = \bigcup \{N(v):v\in S\}$. A *bijective neighborhood map* is a bijection $\varphi:V\to V$ such that for all $v\in V$ we have $\varphi(v) \in N(v)$.

Clearly, a necessary condition for a graph $G=(V,E)$ to have a bijective neighborhood map is that

> (C) for all non-empty $S\subseteq V$ we have $|S|\leq |N(S)|$.

(A very similar condition is central to [Hall's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem).)

**Question.** Is (C) also sufficient for a graph $G$ to have a bijective neighborhood function?

Comment: (What Gjergji said:) This is also Halls theorem in disguise, with V being of size at least 2.  Just duplicate V, and have a directed graph from V to the copy with v goes to (copy of w) if v w is in the graph. Hall's theorem produces the bijection.  Gerhard "Not A Single Rib Needed" Paseman, 2019.01.10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually a special case of Hall's theorem itself, rather than an extension of it. To each such graph $G$ you can associate a bipartite graph $G'$ with vertex set two copies of $V$, which we can denote $V_1,V_2$, and edges between two vertices in different copies whenever their copies in $V$ were connected by an edge.

Now just notice that a bijective neighborhood function for $G$ is the same as a perfect matching for $G'$ and the condition is the same as the one in Hall's theorem, therefore it is necessary and sufficient.